# "JBoss Tools Java Standard Tools AngularJS" will be ignored because it is already installed

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, jboss-developer-studio

Using `JBoss Studio` and importing sample `jboss-forge-html5-archetype`.  When you click next; shows that plugin `AngularJS Eclipse` needs to be installed. When I try Download and Install it fails. It says it is already installed.

Has anyone seen this issue before?  Where does `JBoss Studio` keep it's log files? Where does `JBOss Studio` list it's plugins? How do you un-install a plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Log files are stored the same way as plain Eclipse does. Check in your ~/devstudio/ folder for .log files, or check your workspace's folder for a .log file. Or check the Error Log view while running Devstudio.

To list installed plugins / features, from within Devstudio,select Help > About. You can also uninstall features (not plugins) from that dialog.

If a feature needed by a quick start is already installed then you shouldn't need to reinstall it... But maybe you need to update it?

What version of Devstudio are you running? Which OS & version?  Which JDK vendor & version?